# Why are lawyers not called "doctor"?

Tags: united-states, degree, titles, law

I don't quite understand the education process for lawyers, but I do understand there are a number of different degrees, and one of them is 'JD', the *juris doctor*. My Latin is quite rusty, but I believe that is "Doctor of Law."

So why are they not called "doctor" in common practice, like any PhD is? Is the JD actually not similar to a doctorate program? If not, then why does it take the name *doctor*?

I understand that the JD is what they call a "1st degree" and there are even higher degrees. The LLM, for example, is a "Master of Laws", which really confuses things now because "master" degrees are normally less than "doctor" degrees. So if a JD is not not called a "doctor" for some logical reason, what about the LLM, since it is a higher degree?

---

I'm coming from an American perspective, so I would like an answer from an American perspective, please.

Comment: The vast majority of PhDs are almost never called "doctor", it's generally used for medical doctors.

Comment: @CapeCode Where is that? All the one's I know *are* called "doctor".

Comment: Have you read [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juris_Doctor)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, [and it sounds like a pretty involved degree to me.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juris_Doctor#Standard_Juris_Doctor_curriculum)

Comment: A few months ago I saw the film _Conspiracy_, released in 2010, about the Wannsee conference of January 1942 at which the policy of genocide against Jews was was made to government ministers by an SS general. In that film, the general repeated addressed two lawyers as "Doctor".  So that is one time and place where that title was used for lawyers.

Comment: The pretentious PhDs do demand to be called doctor.

Comment: @matthew Pretentiousness is not a requirement to want recognition for your contributions to the field.

Comment: "attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed"

Answer (score 8):

The American Bar Association has [a nice explanatory essay that answers exactly this question](http://www.abajournal.com/magazine/article/lawyers_are_doctors_too/).

In essence, in the United States, the J.D. degree is quite new, with lawyers having previously received a professional degree that was not called a doctorate.  As such, it has generally been considered problematically confusing to call a lawyer "doctor" and also possibly unethical as undue self-promotion (lawyers used to be prohibited even from advertising in many areas).